# AWS S3 bucket redirect vs DNS CNAME for subdomain in static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

[AWS S3 website hosting guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html) recommend to setup a subdomain in a way which is not clear for me

is there any reason why AWS recommend to setup an A record (alias) to an S3 bucket for the (www) subdomain and the subdomain then later redirect to another S3 bucket?

would not is be better just to setup a CNAME DNS record instead of this double redirection?

Answer (score 0):

That documentation can be confusing.

First, the redirect they're talking about is from www.example.com to example.com.

Second, when setting up the A record using route53, you set it up as an "alias" to your s3 bucket. Internally route53 takes care of finding the IP address to associate with the A record. However, if you use another DNS provider, you would use a CNAME record.

More info can be found in [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/).